# BeautifulSoup No Attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to make a manga downloader. So far so good. But I'm so tired because I've been doing this all day.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

title = input("Title: ")
chapter = input("Chapter: ")
result = requests.get("http://www.mangapanda.com/{}/{}".format(title, chapter))
src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
find = soup.find(id="selectpage").findAll('option')  # A drop down menu

for i in range(len(find)):  # Find how many options are in the drop down menu
    result2 = requests.get("http://www.mangapanda.com/{}/{}/{}".format(title, chapter, i + 1))
    src2 = result2.content
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(src2, "html.parser")
    image = soup2.find(id="img").get('src') 
    title = soup2.find(id="img").get('alt')
    with open(title + ".jpeg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(image).content)
```

When I test it and write, "bleach", "4"
It Gives me an error

```
image = soup2.find(id="img").get('src')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Which is weird since it downloads the first page.

Thanks In Advance!
Also it worked earlier, it downloaded everything but I changed a few lines here and there and I don't know the rest.. I'm so dumb.

Comment: `soup2.find(id="img")` is returning `None`

Comment: why is it returning None? I've looked the site with google inspect and i see an "id='img'".

Comment: which site? you're looping through a bunch of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edited]
the problem is when you do `title = soup2.find(id="img").get('alt')` you change the variable `title` you are using in `requests.get("http://www.mangapanda.com/{}/{}/{}".format(title, chapter, i + 1))`. Try to use a variable with a different name.

Comment: using `.get()` is just fine and the problem is with `None` being returned by `soup2.find()` call

Comment: which title and chapter are you using? I've tested title = "battle-frenzy" and chapter = '1' and it worked for me

Comment: why is it returning None? I've looked the site with google inspect and i see an "id='img'".

Comment: if you use the title and chapter correctly it will not return None. I tested with  title = "battle-frenzy" and chapter = '1' and it worked perfectly. It is probably a consequence of the URL you are trying. Can you tell me the title and chapter you have tested?

Comment: bleach, 4. I've also tried naruto, 2. Because these were the chapters with the fewest pages.

Comment: ok, i found the problem and edited the answer. It was just that you were chenge the variable title from the request in the second loop of the for

Comment: lol, thanks! Guess I was just too tired to realize.